# How to deal with a column that has just date (%m-%d-%Y) and datetime ('%m-%d-%Y %H:%i') records in the same column in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, date, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to convert a date column of string type to date type.

I use the below query in AWS Athena:

```
SELECT col0, col1, col2, date_parse(replace(col3, '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y') AS start_date
FROM "bucket"."table"
WHERE col3 <> ''
```

This works for some records because some dates are formatted like this: `12/08/2019`
But it fails for other dates which are formatted like this: `7/1/2019 0:06`
Some other dates are formatted like: `2020/04/10 08:39`

These different format dates exist in the same column. Dealing with dirty data here... I understand why my query fails because I only have `'%m-%d-%Y'` format in there. Just wondering how would I deal with something like this so that it can deal with all 3 formats in one query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run through the various combinations like so using a combination of `Coalesce` and `try`.

The various date time formats are available from [this presto documentation page](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html).

```
SELECT
    col0,
    col1,
    col2,
    Coalesce(
        try(date_parse(col3, '%m/%d/%Y')),
        try(date_parse(col3, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')),
        try(date_parse(col3, '%e/%c/%Y %k:%i'))
    ) AS start_date
FROM "bucket"."table"
WHERE col3 <> ''
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for most of my data. I checked the documentation but there is no information about parsing something with a timezone. Such as `6/12/2020 9:54 AM EDT` 
I tried different variations of `date_parse(replace(example_time, '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i %p %x'`

Comment: Is the format for this meant to start with month-day-year, and do they support double digits always?

Comment: Yes it is meant to start with month-day-year and yes they support double digits.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is to use CASE WHEN col3 LIKE ..., trim off the times for timed flavors, call date parse once with the right second arg format.  Also, if you find more exceptions, you can WHEN more LIKE expressions.